# How to programmatically clear application data(other apps data)

Tags: android, facebook, adb

First,i want to logout facebook app in my app,so i try facebook SDK:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

no work.
then i try to clean login information by clear other apps application data on root device.
this one can work on adb shell:

```
adb shell pm clear com.facebook.katana
```

when i run this programmatically:

```
Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm clear com.facebook.katana");
```

it does not work,i have no idea to figure out how to logout facebook app in my app,or how can i execute su commands to clear other apps application data.
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: are you trying to logout facebook app from another app ? or simply trying to logout facebook.

Comment: yes....logout facebook app from another app